# Marking an assembly

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying to make a multi tenated mvc website where views can be overridden for each tenant.

I'm using [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) in order to be able to load views from a compiled assembly (with some modifications to allow multiple assemblies).

So now I need to have a way to identify Dlls in the bin that contain views. Currently I'm just creating a dummy class (`Class1`) and looping through `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()` to see what asssemblies include that dummy class

I can imagine a few possiblities.

1. Create an interface `IViewPlugin` and assign that to my `Class1` in each view plugin assembly
2. Name each assembly `MyCompany.Presentation.Views.Plugins.[ClientName]` and include all plugins that match.

Are there any other better ways to mark assemblies as being a 'plugin' assembly when the assemblies themself don't have any actual classes in them (unless I specifically create one for purposes of identifying plugin assemblies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class PluginAssemblyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And apply it on the assembly:

```
[assembly: PluginAssembly]
```

You can then check if the assembly has the attribute:

```
if (assembly.IsDefined(typeof(PluginAssemblyAttribute), false)
    ...
```

Comment: Excellent, I had a feeling something like this might be possible but wasnt sure exactly how